# Reduce time lag in loading a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, time

I have a `UIView` that contains more than 20 `UIButtons`. On clicking each of these buttons, i reveal a distinct `UIView` containing `UIPickerView` and two `UIButtons`('OK','CANCEL') as its subviews(each button corresponds to revealing separate and distinct `UIVIews`).

I have created all the `UIViews`(20 of them) through IB and set all of them to be hidden initially. So whenever i click a button, it reveals a view and on clicking 'OK' or 'CANCEL' hides the view again.

The problem is when this View Controller is pushed from another, it takes a long time to load(like 5 seconds) and i'm suspecting the time lag is due to loading all the subviews before the parent `UIView` appears.

I want to reduce or nullify this time lag.

**EDIT:**

I have trimmed code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     @try
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NavigationBarButtonItems *nav=[[NavigationBarButtonItems alloc]init];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [nav BarButtonItems];


        //the following properties are only for 'quantity' button and its view whereas the original method contains same properties set for all 20 buttons and its views.
        _quantityView.layer.cornerRadius=8;
        _quantityView.clipsToBounds=YES;
        _quantityButton.layer.cornerRadius=8;
        _quantityView.hidden=YES;


        //DEFAULT SELECTED VALUES
        selectedQuantity=@"";

        //only quantity array is initialised here to populate its pickerview. The actual code contains more than 20 arrays initalised for each picker view
        NSArray *quantityData=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)  [quantityData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

        quantityArray=quantityData;

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
       NSLog(@"Medications-> View did Load-> %@",exception.name);
    }
}
```

This is one such `UIButton`('QUANTITY') and the `UIView`('QUANTITYVIEW') to be shown when clicked:

```
- (IBAction)OnClickQuantityButton:(id)sender
{
    @try
    {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_mainView setNeedsDisplay];
            CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(160, _mainScrollView.contentOffset.y+228);
            _quantityView.center= centerPoint;
            _quantityView.hidden=NO;
        });
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Medications-> quantity button-> %@",exception.name);
    }
}


- (IBAction)OnClickQuantityOkButton:(id)sender
{
    @try
    {
        _quantityLabel.text=selectedQuantity;
        _quantityView.hidden=YES;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Medications-> quantity ok button-> %@",exception.name);
    }
}

- (IBAction)OnClickQuantityCancelButton:(id)sender
{
        _quantityView.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some codes? Thanks.

Comment: Why not create each of the 20 UIViews when you need them. Try "lazy instantiation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.

1. All 20 UIView's are having the same UI stuffs like Picker view and 2 Buttons (OK, Cancel).
2. Picker view datasource may be different.
3. So create a single UIView which will have those stuffs and based on the picker view is going to be shown, you can pass/ show the different data.
4. You can also differentiate 20 pickers by specifing tag value of

   pickerview.tag = one enum constants(20 values).

Thats' it.

**what if all 20 UIViews contain different UI elements as their subviews?**

1. Don't use the IB
2. All of them will be created when you create the view
3. Adopt the lazy loading/creation
4. Write custom function or class which will create & give the view(One of your 20)
5. You are not going to show all of them.
6. create programatically as you needed to show them to the user.

Comment: what if all 20 UIViews contain different UI elements as their subviews?

Comment: your question has been answered. see the updated answer